# How to merge column values in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
    property_duplicate_map = {}
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        property_value = row[property]
        name = row['name']
        if name in property_duplicate_map:
            new_value = property_value + '|' + property_duplicate_map[name]
            property_duplicate_map[name] = new_value
            df = df.drop([index])
        else:
            property_duplicate_map[name] = property_value
        df.loc[index, property] = property_duplicate_map[name]
```

My dataframe may have duplicates like below:

```
Name Type Alias

aa   b  m
aa   b  n
```

My code above is supposed to merge the 2 rows into one as below:

```
aa  b m|n
```

The problem seems to be the df.drop(index). For example, if it drops the row index '12' for 'aa b m', the row is going away, and the following df.loc[index, property] = ... doesn't work.

There should be a way to do this. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
In [923]: df
Out[923]: 
  Name Type Alias
0   aa    b     m
1   aa    b     n

In [924]: df.groupby(['Name','Type'])['Alias'].apply('|'.join)
Out[924]: 
Name  Type
aa    b       m|n
Name: Alias, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ideally, I shouldn't explicitly use the column name ['Name', 'Type'] because the column count may be different for different dataframe. Only the 'name' and 'alias' columns are known.